# I am Facing this Issue after running First Webdriver script

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm getting the following error :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type. ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type   at firstproject/firstprojetone.MyLatestClass.main(MyLatestClass.java:14)
```

I have Installed Java 11.0.2 version, Ecllipse IDE 2018-12(64 Bit) and Lib and Configured with ecllipse IDE.

Java programs are executing successfully.

Answer (score 0):

In general, in case of any problems with your import or package name, it results in the exception. Deletion of the package name or fixing import errors might help resolving the issue.

The problem may be even clear, if you can share your code

Comment: Here is the Code Priyanka, Please Review.


package firstprojetone;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class MyLatestClass {
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\Chromedriver.exe");

  WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
 driver.get("http://google.com");
}
}

Comment: Can you share your project structure

Comment: http://www.screencast.com/t/NT3ogLTJ51

Answer (score 0):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: WebDriver cannot be resolved to a type.
```

You need to add selenium webdriver jar files to the project to get rid of that

```
right click on project-->goto build path-->configure build path-->click on "Add external jars"-->add selenium jar files from your local machine-->click ok-->now mouseover on WebDriver in your code-->click "import webdriver"--now run your code-->you will get rid of the exception.
```

After adding your jar you need to do some modification as per your comments i found, you write

> driver.get("google.com");

and it will throw error invalid URL. you need to use below syntax.

> driver.get("https://www.google.com");

Hope this helps.

Comment: Please check the Jar files added:
http://www.screencast.com/t/N7rogjSo7h

Comment: jar looks ok. Are you still getting the error?

Comment: Yes, Same Error getting.

Comment: I guess there is some problem with the compatibility. What do you think?

Comment: Possibly.start with a fresh project and see what you get.

Comment: did you import `webdriver` in your code as i mentioned?

Comment: http://www.screencast.com/t/GkJrQdNKkajy
After clicking on Chrome driver, this output appearing.

Comment: You have downloaded wrong chrome driver you need to download latest one 73 and browser version also 73 http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: Google Chrome Version is 72.0.3626.121 (64-bit) and downloaded  chromedriver 2.46. Check screenshot
http://www.screencast.com/t/apOeM4OL2

Comment: @VandanaRani,You need to download selenium `webDriver 2.46` as well nd add it to your project build path to make it compatible

Comment: search this on google `selenium webdriver 2.46.0  for java download`